# iptables MASQUERADE and SNAT together

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Good people,

I have a network having the following setup

`eth0 10.216.11.41` internet facing

`eth1 192.168.0.4` internal network interacting with other machines within the internal network.

Id like to use this machine as a gateway with the following requirements.

1. All traffic from the internal network going out to yahoo.com be SNATted with a --to 10.216.11.40 through eth0
2. Everything else to be MASQUARADed out via eth0 whose ip is 10.216.11.41

I had hoped to achieve this vis

```
#everything to yahoo be snatted
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.216.11.40 --destination yahoo.com 

#everything else be masqueraded
iptables --t nat --A POSTROUTING --o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But alas the SNATting rule doesn't take a destination.

How can I achieve the above requirements?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the SNAT in a new separate chain.

Then where you have the SNAT now, you need to write a rule that tests the destination IP, and if it's equvialent to the one you want to do this for, to jump to the chain you made above.

---

Near the beginning of your iptables file

`/sbin/iptables -t nat -N SNATChain`

to create a chain in the `nat` table called "SNATChain"

Then, replace this:

```
#everything to yahoo be snatted
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.216.11.40 --destination yahoo.com
```

with this:

```
#if the destination IP matches yahoo, throw it to SNATChain
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 --destination yahoo.com -j SNATChain
```

and then populate your SNATChain with the rule you want

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A SNATChain -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.216.11.40
```

I believe that's how to do it.  Been awhile since I've messed with `iptables`.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. kindly provide a sample command to achieve what you have written

Comment: Try that out.  Please note that Netfilter doesn't resolve IP addresses (above you're going to get whatever yahoo.com resolves to when the rules are applied), so if `yahoo.com` changes their IP address (or uses multiple in a CDN setup) you'll need to refresh the rules for it to work.